# Wait for ajax calls from another function without using global variables?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm not a fan of using globals but I couldn't figure out another way of achieving what I wanted to do:

```
window.op_ajax = null;

function addsomestuff_intohtmltable() {
    $.when( op_ajax ).done(function ( data ) {
        //NOW we are sure that the html-table is created with a div 
        // thas has class indigo

        //Add some content into div with class indigo
    });
}

function create_htmltable() {        
    var op_ajax = $.ajax({            
        type: 'POST',   //etc, data etc...
    });

    op_ajax.done(function(content_data) {
       //Create a table with some html
       //In this table we have a div with indigo
    });                        

    op_ajax.fail(function(ts) {         
       alert(ts.responseText);
    });
}
```

Above code does what it has to do. It waits for a html-table to created through an ajax-call, and then adds some content into part of that created html-table inside another function.

I never know when these two functions are executed and how long time they take. I'm using window.op_ajax to use a defered object, but is there a better way to to this (without using global variables)? I'm using some other ajax-functionality as well.

Comment: why not using the callBack `$.ajax.done`  to run the `addsomestuff_intohtmltable` function ?

Comment: Ah. of course. I were just thinking too complicated :-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: ok, I make an answer to close it ;)

Comment: In that code above, you have a global variable op_ajax and a locally scoped variable op_ajax. The when() does not reference the Ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I see, you can use two way :

The ajax callback :

```
function addsomestuff_intohtmltable() {

        //Add some content into div with class indigo
}

function create_htmltable() {        
    $.ajax({            
        type: 'POST',   //etc, data etc...
    })
    .done(function(content_data) {
       //Create a table with some html
       addsomestuff_intohtmltable(); // << run the second function 
    });                        
    op_ajax.fail(function(ts) {         
       alert(ts.responseText);
    });
}
```

**It's the best choice and how you should deal with this kind of problem**

---

The other one is for advanced stuff, when the callBack is not enough :

You bind a [listener](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with your function(s) on the parent element, like an `updated` on the `<table>`, and you run it with a [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sometimes you just think to complicated :-)